# Point RStudio to remote R instance

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to have RStudio running on my local machine (os x) and the R executable on a remote computer.

I'm aware that I could run RStudio Server on the remote machine and connect to it using a web interface, however I abhor using web interfaces for things like this due to the delays and limited ability to move windows and use shortcuts.

Since RStudio isn't stand alone but points to an R executable elsewhere on the local machine (in a location that can be varied), it seems like in theory this pointer could be to a remote location. (Is there some reason this is incorrect?)

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: You could just try and see what happens. The naive attempt would be to modify the R version in `Tools/Global Options`. If the remote machine is on a network drive, RStudio shouldn't notice the difference.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that just pointing to the remote location would mean that the actual process would still be running on the local machine.  The goal is to do the processing on the remote machine.